# What physical quantity remains equal in different frames?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, charge, tensor-calculus

I recently came across a problem which involved going into rotating frames. And it was pretty tiring. (And difficult..). So I wondered if there was some quantity that you could measure from the ground frame and then the rotating frame and then compare them.
But then again rotating frames are non inertial frames.
Is there some physical quantity that remains equal at least in inertial frames?
I could think of charge.. And that's pretty much it.

Comment: _"Is there some physical quantity that remains equal at least in inertial frames?"_ also (rest) mass, spin etc.

Comment: mass, invariant length ($c^2dt^2-dr^2$), $E^2-c^2B^2$ (for electric $E$ and magnetic $B$ fields) etc. Take any four-tensors, contract them to get a scalar, and this scalar will be (intertial) frame-invariant.

Comment: Magnitude of acceleration is one.

Comment: also length of a rigid object.

Comment: This appears to be a list-based question, which is generally considered off-topic as too broad. Please see [the help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for details of what types of questions to avoid asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of those quantities. As you pointed out, things like charge, mass, and other scalars are conserved. However, perhaps the most important conserved quantities are given by Noether's theorems. Of course, the specific quantity will depend on your problem, but it is always interesting to apply this theorem to get a better idea of your system.